# Caesar Cipher / file input not working

Tags: c++

I am working on a program to encrypt and decrypt a .txt file with the Caesar cipher. (keyboard input is optional)I have made an effort but am stumped.

What i have right now is a basic or i guess somewhat elaborate menu structure already. 
I have gotten to where i should be calling the information from the file and it just calls garbage or is garbage one way or the other.

Here is my code it runs to the input part and then ends after the input.

its option 1 option 1 and then any number and then it runs the file input and then ends.

Thanks in advance. I have pretty much looked everywhere and tried it 3 or 4 different ways all to no avail.

So what i want to know is what should i do to fix the file input and suggestions on how to then take that array or string how ever you suggest and change the ascii values of each character by the shift value.

Thanks ahead of time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cctype>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int decryptce();
int encryptcefile();
int encryptce();
int outputce();
int encmenu();
int decmenu();

int main()
{
    int t;
      //main menu
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "This is a Caesar Cipher, please select [1] or [2]" << endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "[1] Encrypt"<<endl;
    cout << "[2] Decrypt"<<endl;
    cout << "What is your choice:\t";
    cin  >> t;
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;

    // menu switch statement
    switch (t)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            cout << "\n running encryption:\n\n";
            encmenu();
            break;

        }
        case 2:
        {
            cout << "\n running decryption:\n\n";
            decmenu();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout<< "Thats not a 1 or 2"<<endl;
            cout<< "Relaunch the program"<<endl;
            system ("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int encmenu()
{

    int t;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "You selected: Encrypt with Caesar Cypher"<<endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout <<"Do you want to enter from a file or the keyboard?"<<endl;
    cout <<"Enter [1] From file, or [2] From Keyboard"<<endl;
    cout <<"Run option:\t";
    cin  >> t;
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    // encrypt menu switch

    switch (t)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            encryptcefile();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            encryptce();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            cout<< "Thats not a 1 or 2"<<endl;
            cout<< "Relaunch the Program"<<endl;
            system ("pause");
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

// decrypt main menu
int decmenu()
{
    int h;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "You selected: Decrypt with Caesar Cypher"<<endl;
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "Reading from Data.txt in main file directory:";
    cout << "\n"<<endl;
    cout << "Ofset is:\t";
    cin  >> h;
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    return h;
}

int decryptce()
{
    return 0;
}


int encryptcefile()
{
    // for figuring out what to do with negatives
    /*
    letter = x;
    letter = ( letter + shift + 26 ) % 26;
    // add 26 in case the shift is negative
    letter += x; // back to ascii code

    */
    char c,i;

    int num=0;
    int shift;
    ofstream ofile;
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("data.txt");
    ofile.open("Encrypted.txt");
    if(!ifile)
    {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if(!ofile)
    {
        cout << "Error Opening File" << endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (ifile.good())
    {
        c = ifile.get();
        if (c=='\n')num++;
        {
            cout << "Is: " << num << " Long. \r";
            Sleep(1);
            fflush ( stdin );
        }
    }

    cout << "File is: " << num << " characters Long.\n"<<endl;
    cout << "\n-----------------------------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout << "What is the shift for the encryption:\t";

    // ---------------------working here-------------------
    cin >> shift;

    const int xx = num+1;
    char *arraye;
    char *arrayce;
    int j;

    arraye = new char [xx];
    arrayce = new char [xx];
    arrayce[xx];
    ifile.read(arrayce,xx);

    for(j=0;j<xx;j++)
    {
        arraye[j]=arrayce[j];
        cout << arrayce[j]<< endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

int encryptce()
{
    return 0;
}

int outputce()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don’t parse the whole code, only the relevant section and preferably a *minimal working* example. Most of the code you’ve posted is completely irrelevant to the question, and is distracting.

Answer (score 3):

This is generally a bad way to parse through the file. `ifile.good()` will be true until you try to read *past* the end of the file, which means it will read once too many times.

```
while (ifile.good())
    {
        c = ifile.get();
        if (c=='\n')num++;
        {
            cout << "Is: " << num << " Long. \r";
            Sleep(1);
            fflush ( stdin );
        }
    }
```

You `if` statement is misformed there. Right now, it executes `num++;` when condition is true, but the block part executes in every `while` iteration.
You store the number of line feed ('\n') characters in `num` and later in the code say "file is `num` characters long." So I'm not sure whether you want to count the lines or determine the size of the file. I don't know what the purpose of `fflush(stdin);` either.

An easier, cleaner and more correct way is to put the read statement in the `while` condition, that way you don't enter the loop when the read fails. So if you want to read the file line by line, do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> file_by_lines; // pick a better name :)
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ifile, line))
{
    num += line.length();
    file_by_lines.push_back(line);
}
std::cout << "File is " << num << " characters Long." << std::endl;
```

There, you've got the file stored in a vector, there's no need to dynamically allocate space for the file by yourself anymore, the vector takes care of that.

Alternatively, if you need to read char by char:

```
// get the size of the file

ifile.seekg (0, ios::end);
size_t length = ifile.tellg();
ifile.seekg (0, ios::beg);  // move read pointer back to the beggining

char* buffer = new char[length];
ifile.read(buffer, length);

// free the allocated memory once you're done.

delete [] buffer;
```

One more thing. In future, consider narrowing down your code to the actual problem. You don't need to post your entire code when you only have a problem with (in your case) input.
200 lines of poorly formatted code makes it less likely you'll get people to help you. Read about Short, Self Contained, Compilable Example here: http://sscce.org/

Hope that helps, and sorry for my cumbersome english :)

Comment: Thank you i greatly appreciate the help. I know my code has some major flaws. Ill remember next time i post, thanks again.